# How to fetch/read otp from outlook in selenium webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm automating web page where I have to enter email id and click on verification code button then otp will goes to respected email Inbox. Which(otp) I have to read and enter into next input field on web and validate.

Can someone help on this scenario. Not sure how I can automate this scenario

Comment: First of all specify what do you mean with 'outlook'. For MS Outlook as windows app you can use Windows Application Driver, see https://medium.com/software-testing-break-and-improve/tutorial-windows-app-automation-using-winappdriver-and-java-5be661335b25. For any web environment you can use Selenium of course.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.